# This code opens and holds open the file referenced at 'oldfile'. Where does the opening of the file occur?

Tags: python, windows, for-loop, os.walk

I'm not a frequent programmer but I have some understanding of what I'm doing so I hope I will be able to understand the answers I get!

I have been creating a python script to go through a folder, find video files above a certain size/resolution ratio and re-encode them using handbrake.

When I run the code below it all works fine until line 104 (which is part of the file manipulation to clean up the folder after the re-encoding has been done)

```
# Run Program: 
# python "R:\Documents\Scripts\Filebot\hb-postprocess-folder.pyw" "%D"
#
# Test with Console:
# python "R:\Documents\Scripts\Filebot\hb-postprocess-folder.pyw" "R:\Movies"

import sys
import subprocess
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil
import cv2
import time
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

sizecutoff1080p = 9
sizecutoff4K = 12 

'''for line in sys.argv:
    print(line)'''


# configuration
if len(sys.argv) >= 4:
    sizecutoff4K = int(sys.argv[3])
if len(sys.argv) >=3:
    sizecutoff1080p = int(sys.argv[2])
if  len(sys.argv)<2:
    raise RuntimeError("Need to at least specify a folder to work on - preferably some sizes for cut offs too")

print("cutoffs")
print(str(sizecutoff1080p))
print(str(sizecutoff4K))

GBsize = 1073741824
hbroot = 'R:\Converted\AutoHandbrake'
output = 'R:/'
hbtemp = hbroot
if not os.path.exists(hbroot):
        os.makedirs(hbroot)

# required args
#directory = 'R:\Movies'
directory = sys.argv[1]
#directory = os.getenv(radarr_movie_path)

directory=os.path.abspath(directory)

'''print(kind)'''

head, tail = os.path.split(directory)
hbtemp = os.path.join(hbroot,tail)

if not os.path.exists(hbtemp):
    os.makedirs(hbtemp)

for dirname, subdirlist, filelist in os.walk(directory):
    parent=os.path.abspath(dirname)
    print('Parent path is', str(parent))
    relpath=os.path.relpath(parent, directory)
    hbparent= os.path.join(hbtemp,relpath)
    if not os.path.exists(hbparent):
        os.makedirs(hbparent)
    for fname in filelist:
        sizecutoff=sizecutoff1080p    
        #print('File is', str(fname))
        vid=cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(parent, fname))
        height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        vid.release
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        if ((height > 1080) or (width > 1920)):
            sizecutoff=sizecutoff4K
        #print(sizecutoff)
        #input("Press Enter to continue...")
        if (( fname.endswith('.mp4') or fname.endswith('.mkv') or fname.endswith('.m4v') or fname.endswith('.avi')) and (os.stat(os.path.join(parent, fname)).st_size > sizecutoff * GBsize)):
            print('File is', str(fname))
            print('Size is', str(os.stat(os.path.join(parent, fname)).st_size / GBsize), 'vs. a limit of ', sizecutoff)
            print('Running Handbrake')
            hbcommand = [
                'HandBrakeCLI',
                '--preset-import-gui',
                '--preset=WillSurround4k',
                '-x threads=2',
                '-i', os.path.join(parent, fname),
                '-o', os.path.join(hbtemp, relpath, fname),
                '1>"'+os.path.join(hbtemp, relpath, 'hbprogress.txt')+'"',
                '2>"'+os.path.join(hbtemp, relpath, 'hblog.txt')+'"'
            ]
            with open(os.path.join (hbroot, 'WorkingFile.txt'),"w") as text_file:
                text_file.write(str(os.path.join(parent, fname)))

            print(' '.join(hbcommand))
            subprocess.run(hbcommand, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, check = True)


            oldfile=os.path.join(parent,fname)
            fnameroot=os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
            fnamenew=fnameroot + '.mkv'
            print(str(fnamenew))
            newfile=os.path.join(hbtemp, relpath, fnamenew)
```

This Next Line is where the error occurs

```
            shutil.move(oldfile,hbroot)
            print('Moved old file')
            time.sleep(5)
            shutil.copy2(newfile,oldfile)
            print('Copied New file')
            time.sleep(5)
            os.remove(os.path.join(hbroot,fname))
            print('Deleted old file')
            time.sleep(5)

            '''
            # Run filebot
            command = [
                'filebot', '-script', 'fn:amc',
                '--output', output,
                '--action', 'move',
                '--conflict', 'override',
                '-non-strict', parent,
                '--log-file', output + '/amc.log',
                '--def',
                    'plex=127.0.0.1:3x2jXXkqfWzabNTfTvCx',
                    'clean=y',
                    'extras=y',
                    'music=y',
                    'unsorted=y',
                    'artwork=y',
                    'minFileSize=20000000'
                ]

            print(' '.join(command))

            # execute command (and hide cmd window)
            subprocess.run(command, creationflags=0x08000000, check = True)
            '''

    shutil.rmtree(os.path.abspath(hbparent))

shutil.rmtree(os.path.abspath(hbtemp))
```

The error which occurs is WinError 32 (I'm running this on windows). This error is windows' way of saying that the file in question is being used by another process and cannot be removed. All the other instances of this error being asked about on the web are people using f.open() and f.close() incorrectly instead of with open.
My problem is slightly different. I can't work out what line of the code I have written has opened the file. I have checked that it is not handbrake by replacing that call with a copy of the file from the input to output locations and the WinError 32 is still the same. I thought for a time that it was my use of cv2 keeping the file open but I've now done my research on that and added the lines to clean up the opening of the file and close the handles:

```
vid.release
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

All this has lead me to the conclusion that it must be something in the way I'm using either os.walk or the path fname. But my understanding was that a path variable (like fname) is just a specialised kind of string and doesn't actually manipulate the file itself?

Either way I ahve spent a long time on this trying to understand where I open the file fname so that I can close it again before I need to move it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  This code is hardly minimal.

Comment: ok I'll try to remove a lot of it to get to a point where it can be reproduced

Comment: What does `cv2.VideoCapture` do - Does that open the file ? Should `vid.release` be `vid.release()` ?
If it does open the file name then it is the same file that you try to move later.

Comment: changing to vid.release() solves it. Thank you very much for your help